# Compiled PuTTY source on Rocky Linux 9.1 but where is pterm?

Tags: putty

Rocky Linux 9.1 (5.14.0-162.6.1.el9_1.x86_64). PuTTY is not available from EPEL so I'm compiling putty-0.78.  It compiled `pscp`, `psftp`, etc but not `pterm` or `putty`.

Sorry I couldn't find a PuTTY forum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To compile GUI tools like PuTTY or PTerm, you need GTK.

Without GTK, only command-line tools (like pscp and psftp) are built.

Comment: On Rocky Linux 9, it was gtk3-devel.x86_64.  That was it - thank you.